# Modificar fichero txt con exclusion de datos

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola buenas soy un poco nuevo en java, tengo un fichero con el formato como el de la imagen, necesito coger la información del fichero y crear un fichero nuevo cogiendo los datos de delante de "container:" y saber mediante un fichero de exclusion si esos datos tengo que guardarlos, he probado con la clase FileReader de java y utilizo el método contains que me filtra el fichero por la palabra o caracter que pongas y solo te muestra ese carácter o lo omite del fichero. Como podría guardar en un fichero los datos de container: saltar la siguiente información que contenga container: y pasar a la siguiente. Muchas gracias por todo.

Comment: Bienvenido, es muy importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask],  saludos.